# how to remove rows when they don't meet a criteria

Tags: r

I have been busy with a data which looks like below

```
df<- structure(list(V1 = structure(1:6, .Label = c("A", "B", "C", 
"D", "E", "F"), class = "factor"), V2 = structure(1:6, .Label = c("AA", 
"BB", "CC", "DD", "EE", "FF"), class = "factor"), V3 = structure(c(6L, 
5L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("hddu", "jfhu", "jshsg", "kduf", 
"Tlsu", "Trsm"), class = "factor"), V4 = c(1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 
6L), V5 = c(0L, 2L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 5L), V6 = c(0L, 0L, 4L, 6L, 0L, 
7L), V7 = c(0L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 8L), V8 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 
0L), V9 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 7L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("V1", "V2", 
"V3", "V4", "V5", "V6", "V7", "V8", "V9"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

looks like this

```
  V1 V2    V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9
1  A AA  Trsm  1  0  0  0  0  0
2  B BB  Tlsu  2  2  0  0  0  0
3  C CC  kduf  0  0  4  5  0  0
4  D DD  hddu  0  4  6  0  0  7
5  E EE jshsg  5  0  0  0  6  0
6  F FF  jfhu  6  5  7  8  0  0
```

what i want is to remove the rows that they don't have value for at least 2 columns consecutively. For example, they should have for first 2 column, or second two column or third two columns , if they have more, it is ok. 
I want to detect them, and also make an output without them 
in this case

row number 1 , 4 and 5. so I need two output

1- index 1, 4 and 5 (this shows which rows are removed) 
2- The expected output is like this

```
B   BB  Tlsu    2   2   0   0   0   0
C   CC  kduf    0   0   4   5   0   0
F   FF  jfhu    6   5   7   8   0   0
```

Comment: For your input, all rows have value for all columns.  Explain what you really need.  What do you mean by "not having value for some column"?

Comment: @user31264 my mean not having zero

Comment: If you meant not having zero, then what about the 4th row?

Comment: @akrun they should have column V4 and V5, or V6 and V7 or V8 and V9. if they have values, it is ok (my means of value not zero)

Comment: What about V5 and V6 or V6 and V7.  The rules are not clear

Comment: @akrun they must have at least values (not zero) in column V4 and V5, or V6 and V7 or V8 and V9. If they have more, it is OK, but they should have at least in two of these columns values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually pick up two data frames with index which shift horizontally by one and use vectorized `&` to find out if there is any consecutive TRUE and collect the row wise condition with `rowSums` as filtering index:

```
df[rowSums(df[4:8] & df[5:9]) != 0, ]

#   V1 V2   V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9
# 2  B BB Tlsu  2  2  0  0  0  0
# 3  C CC kduf  0  0  4  5  0  0
# 4  D DD hddu  0  4  6  0  0  7
# 6  F FF jfhu  6  5  7  8  0  0
```

If the columns have to be paired every other column, `seq` can be used to generate necessary index:

```
df[rowSums(df[seq(4, 9, 2)] & df[seq(5, 9, 2)]) != 0, ]

#  V1 V2   V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9
#2  B BB Tlsu  2  2  0  0  0  0
#3  C CC kduf  0  0  4  5  0  0
#6  F FF jfhu  6  5  7  8  0  0
```

Comment: that is very good solution but not fully correct. you have row number 4 which should not be in the output. they must have values (not zero) in at least column V4 and V5, or V6 and V7 or V8 and V9.

Comment: Check the updated answer. There is an update about pairing every other column.

Answer (score 1):

The logic is not clear.  But, this seems to work

```
 df[Reduce(`|`, Map(`&`, df[-(1:3)][c(TRUE, FALSE)], df[-(1:3)][c(FALSE, TRUE)])),]
 #  V1 V2   V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9
 #2  B BB Tlsu  2  2  0  0  0  0
 #3  C CC kduf  0  0  4  5  0  0
 #6  F FF jfhu  6  5  7  8  0  0
```